# NSPredicateEditor: add a first row like in Finder

Tags: cocoa, nspredicateeditor

I'm trying to add a sort of ''*first row*'' in the `NSPredicateEditor` like the `Finder` app. Something similar to the screenshot below: In particular I'd like to add a sort of label on the left, like ''Add search options'' and the plus button on the right.

Any clue on how to do this?

[image: Finder screenshot]

By the way: I will not use directly the resulting `NSPredicate` because I use the search field to query a REST server so I was thinking to translate the `NSPredicate` to a proper `NSString` object. Is there another, more appropriate component, or I can use the `NSPredicateEditor` and make the translation later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build the first line by yourself. Add "Seach:" - label and some state-Buttons. 
Then you can add the NSPredicateRuleEditor just under the view with heigh 1 (better 0).

Don't forget to set the Auto-Layout Constraints wisely. 
[image]

Just like that: the big black line is the reduced NSPredicateEditor
Take care about Auto-Layout.. You'll have to expand the view if predicates grow.

Comment: After some time spent trying to create an `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` subclass I realized the same thing: it is a completely independent component! I created it and it works nicely. I still have some other issues (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966386/cocoa-autolayout-insert-and-remove-view-programmatically-at-runtime) but this is solved. Thanks